# Decreasing mouse sensitivity at kernel level

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, mouse, user-input

I have developed a custom-GUI Server, which runs on virtual console of Linux.For mouse-handling purpose, it reads the mouse device file

```
/dev/input/mice
```

and retrieves the event data and updates the pointer position.How can I add the facility of the feature of changing mouse-sensitivity to this software?

```
One solution may be is to change the mouse driver config file.
```

But i dont know where it is located or is there any such options, that fulfills my need.Thank you

Comment: Your application has to do it. Doing it at the kernel level is a bad idea and is insufficient anyway, you would also have to handle acceleration, multitouch, and many other pesky things that X already handles.

Comment: well..Then I am checking that..But I am still curious;do you know the location of the mouse-driver config file?

Comment: There is no such thing as a kernel driver config file. There are module parameters for `psmouse` (e.g. `resolution`), but those are only for PS2 mouses where you have to configure the actual hardware. There is no such things for USB mouses and other type of input devices. If your application mentions a *mouse driver config file*, it belongs to the application.